# SOLVED A-Level logarithm question

Tags: logarithms

So theres a question on one of my logarithm revision sheets that i have no idea how to solve, so i thought id come here to ask for your infinite mathematical wisdom.

Given that $\log_a(y)=\cfrac{3}{2}\ $ and $\log_4(a)=b+2$ Show that $y=2^p$ Where p is an expression in terms of b.

Thank you in advance ~

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Try the log change of base formula to rewrite the first equation like $\log_y a =...$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write the log expressions in exponential form,

$$a^{3/2}=y \;\;\; and \;\;\; 4^{b+2}=a.$$

Substituting $4^{b+2}$ in the first equation for $a$ and using exponent laws quickly yields, $$p=3b+6.$$

(Recall that $(a^{n})^{m}=a^{nm}$)

Comment: Im plenty familiar with exponent laws, but for some reason i really didnt see it that way. Im new to logarithms so this is all rather confusing for the moment. But thank you so much for the help! :)

Comment: No worries. Exponentiation may sometimes be confusing with parentheses. Let me know if you require any additional clarification. Good luck with logarithms